# Reusable snippets in Angular templates

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-ng-if

We can now have `else` snippets, referring to an `<ng-template>`:

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else not">
  Condition satisfied.
  <ng-template #not>
    Condition not satisfied.
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to refer to snippets outside of the context of an `*ngIf`--something like

```
<div>DIV1 <ng-template-call template="shared"></ng-template-call></div>
<div>DIV2 <ng-template-call template="shared"></ng-template-call></div>

<ng-template #shared>This is a shared snippet.</ng-template>
```

What is the correct way to write what I have called `ng-template-call` above?

Yes, I know I could make this into a separate component, but it does not rise to that level. And I could always write:

```
<div *ngIf="false; else shared">
```

but that seems clumsy.

Comment: so the question is not about `ngIf`, you just showed it as an analogy?

Comment: I really don't see why you wouldn't use a component. That's what they're for.

Comment: The #1 reason you wouldn't (want to) use a component is if you don't want a wrapping element. The best general solution to this is `display: contents` which makes the component element behave like it wasn't there. But if there's ever a way to make a component with an optional wrapper I'll be the first to use it!

Answer (score 11):

I think Transclusions is what you're looking for

Here's a sample:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="reusable"></ng-container>

<ng-template #resusable>...</ng-template>
```

For reference: https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content